# Can a jar which is compiled on old java version be used in new applications?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, version

We are planning to upgrade our J2EE application, I worked with a lot of jars before and I know that the version mismatch can be a hard problem to debug. We have all the jars(internal to company and built by some other team so cannot recompile with latest version ) compiled using 1.6 jdk and we are bumping up our application version to 1.7, but we are planning to use 1.6 version jars in our app. Does this work well? If not what should I do to make it compatible?

I'm sure that it will work well but, need some expert opinion on this.
Thank yo

Comment: why don't you simply ask the other team to rebuild with 1.7?

Comment: @wero there are a lot of complex dependencies of jars, meaning a lot of man hours to debug if there is an issue upgrading which they are not ready to put money on.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on Oracle's homepage [regarding compatibility of Java 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) it should be compatibale except for [the following things](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities)

> Binary Compatibility
>
> Java SE 7 is binary-compatible with Java SE 6 except for the
> incompatibilities listed below. Except for the noted incompatibilities,
> class files built with the Java SE 6 compiler will run correctly in Java SE 7.

Quote from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html)